# Custom view in android is looking different in every devices

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am developing custom view in android. I wants to display path in the view. All the point are hard coded like this.

```
  private void loadData(){
                float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                testPath = new Path();
                testPath.moveTo(new Point((int) (242*density), (int) (213*density)));
                testPath.lineTo(new Point((int) (214*density), (int) (209*density)));
                testPath.lineTo(new Point((int) (131*density), (int) (243*density)));
                testPath.lineTo(new Point((int) (96*density), (int) (314*density)));
                testPath.lineTo(new Point((int) (117*density), (int) (403*density)));
                testPath.lineTo(new Point((int) (194*density), (int) (457*density)));
 }


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);{
        canvas.drawLine(0,200,canvas.getWidth(),200,drawPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0,canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2,drawPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()/2,0,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight(),drawPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(testPath, drawPaint);
}
```

But In xxhdpi screen is coming below the base line(middle line). while In the mpdpi its coming above the base line. If I don't multiply points with denisty pixel then path is too small in xxhdpidevices.
Here is mdpi device image.[image]
Here is xxhdpi device  [image]

Comment: your onDraw doesn't take in consideration the screen's density

Comment: so how to make screen equal in each kind of device? I try to multiply points with density pixel but it's not coming proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem statement: If suppose on 1280x720(16:9) device there is a point say P(10, 20), what should be the corresponding point on say 480x854 device(or device of any resolution in the ratio 16:9)

Solution:

```
public int getGeneralizedValueX(int x) {
    return (int) (AppConstants.CANVAS_WIDTH * (x / 1280f));
}

public int getGeneralizedValueY(int y) {
    return (int) (AppConstants.CANVAS_HEIGHT * (y / 720f));
}
```

Note: Above formula holds true across constant ratio of CANVAS_WIDTH & CANVAS_HEIGHT